# Eloquent query distinct sub id

Tags: laravel

I have these models
[image]

I want to make a query that shows me all the products whose stock quantity> 0 and that does not repeat the products.

My query:

```
$stock_products_limit = Stock::distinct('product_id')->where('quantity', '!=', 0)->get();
```

This would be much easier using a size chart relating it to stocks ... but for now I don't have it

I need the model to return me, and then do a foreach:

```
@foreach($stock_products_limit as $stock_product)
 @foreach($stock_product->product->product_images as $i=>$product_image)
  ...
 @endforeach
...
@enforeach
```

In my models I have the hasMany and belongsTo relations made

How could I make the query? I've been trying the distinct, group by ... but nothing works for me. It only removes the ones with quantity 0 and repeats the product ID ...

[image]

[image]

Example of the query I want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(stocks.product_id)
FROM stocks
INNER JOIN products ON stocks.product_id = products.id
WHERE quantity != 0
ORDER BY product_id
LIMIT 10;
```

Another example query (but LIMIT doesn't work with IN)

```
SELECT * from products where id in (SELECT DISTINCT(product_id)
    FROM stocks
    INNER JOIN products ON stocks.product_id = products.id
    WHERE quantity != 0
    ORDER BY product_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the `Stock` model as the starting point, you might want to use the `Product` model. Then you don't even have to think about using `DISTINCT`. Let's use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```php
return Product::whereHas('stocks', function ($query) {
    $query->where('quantity', '>', 0);
})
->limit(10)
->get();
```

Comment: Works!! thank you very much, i didn't know i could do it like that